# react-native-qrcode doesn't fit it's element

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, qr-code

I am using 'react-native-qrcode' library and trying to create a QR Code, it seems to be working up until the point I want to make it take 100% of it's own container.

I've tried to:

- put it in a View, it doesn't work
- use flex: 1 on the above mentioned View and on the QR Code

NOTE: I had to change the WebView in the node_modules since now it is a separate library.

```js
import React from 'react';
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode';

export default function CardDetails({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <QRCode
            value={"Hello World"}
            size={250}
        />
    )
}
```

[image: QR code will won't take up 100%]

Comment: You have to path *static size* to your QrCode ... if you want to make the QrCode take the size of the container ... dynamically calc the size of the container, and then pass it as a prop to your QrCode

Comment: I am not sure if we are talking about the same thing. :) The white rectangle is the QR Code. But the code (black thing) doesn't take the full size of the QR Code element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem originates from the QRCode library. This is the code from the library.
If I change the canvas -> context -> size to size * 4 it is will always cover the whole white space and will fit / dynamically change whenever I pass another size.

P.S. still trying to figure it out why x4 is the solution.

```js
return (
            <View>
                <Canvas
                    context={{
                        size: size,
                        value: this.props.value,
                        bgColor: this.props.bgColor,
                        fgColor: this.props.fgColor,
                        cells: qr(value).modules,
                    }}
                    render={renderCanvas}
                    onLoad={this.props.onLoad}
                    onLoadEnd={this.props.onLoadEnd}
                    style={{height: size, width: size}}
                />
            </View>
        );
```

[image]